# How to prove that a subset in a vector space is an indicatrix?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, norms

Suppose that $\pi:(V_1,F_1)\to V_2$ is a linear surjective map, where $V_1$ and $V_2$ are vector spaces and $F_1$ is a Minkowski norm on $V_1$. Let $B_1$ be the unitary ball on $V_1$. Define $B_2:=\pi(B_1)$ and let $\Sigma_2$ be the board of $B_2$.

If $\Sigma_2$ is an indicatrix with respect to some Mnikowski norm on $V_2$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is. The projection of the convex body enclosed by $\Sigma_1$ is a convex body in the space $V_2$. If you require, as in Finsler geometry, the quadratic convexity, then that is also preserved. In normed spaces this is just the construction of the quotient norm in the quotient of $V_1$ by the kernel of the projection (you can then identify the quotient with $V_2$). This construction comes up in the geometry of isometric submersions in Finsler geometry. See my [paper](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/2001-129-08/S0002-9939-01-05910-X/S0002-9939-01-05910-X.pdf) with Duran.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I am reading exactly this paper and this is why I asked this question here. Which pert of the paper is mentioning this construction?

Comment: the quotient norm on $V_2$ is $F_2$ then?

Comment: Propositions 2.1 and 2.2. Yes, it's just que quotient norm.

Comment: Trying to understand your paper, I have difficulties and some doubts about the parameterization that you are suggesting before Definition 2.2. I mean the vector-valued function $\alpha$. Suppose that $V=R^3$ and the Minkowski norm $F$ is the canonical metric, i.e. $F=||.||$. Define $\alpha: R^2\mapsto S$, where $S$  is the unit sphere, as $\alpha(x,y)=(x,y,\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2})$. Then $F^2(\alpha)=1$ and so each partial derivative of it is zero. In particular $g_{\varphi}(0,0,1)=0$. 
I am wondering the definition provided for the fundamental tensor is well-defined?

Comment: It's supposed to just be the hessian of $\varphi^2$ in the affine space $V$ evaluated at the point $v$. Let me check what we wrote.

Comment: Gee, you are right. It's wrong.  I don't know what I (or we) were thinking, but it was just meant to be the Hessian in an affine space ( and so its well defined, if you don't mess up like we did).

Comment: You mean I can still use Propositions 2.1 and 2.2? 
Where did you use such a parameterization then?

Comment: What parametrization? At every one of its points a smooth quadratically convex body has an oscullating ellipsoid. There is nothing more there. Proposition 2.1 is just the analytic representation of the quotient norm (it holds even when the convex body is not quadratically convex) and Proposition 2.2 is the rather simple statement that when you project a quadratically convex body, then the osculating ellipsoids at the singular points of the projection project themselves to the osculating ellipsoids of the projected body.

Comment: I thought that you used this parametrization to show that $g_{\varphi}(\pi(v))$ is an inner product.

Comment: That would be like calling every tangent vector a parametrization because you can write it as the derivative at time zero of some smooth curve. It was meant to be the hessian of the norm at a nonzero point, but we screwed up writing it and didn't notice until now. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This answers a previous variant of the question above:

Suppose that $V_1=\mathbb{R}^2$ with standard Euclidean metric, and $V_2=\mathbb{R}$. Let $\pi(x,y)=x+2y$. Then $\pi(\Sigma_1)$ contains both $1$ and $2$.

Comment: If $\pi$ is not an isomorphism, then $\Sigma_2$ contains zero.

Comment: What is the problem by containing both 1 and 2?

Comment: You said you wanted $\Sigma_1$ to be the unit sphere. But if $\Sigma_2$ contains both 1 and 2, it is not the boundary of a convex body containing the origin, i.e. not the unit sphere of any Minkowski norm.

Comment: @Majid:   The confusion is caused by the use of the word 'indicatrix', which you described as 'the unitary sphere' instead of as the 'unitary ball'.  The unitary sphere (which is the usual meaning of 'indicatrix') is not convex, while the 'unitary ball' (whose boundary is the 'unitary sphere') is.

Comment: @Robert Bayant unfortunately I did not get what your comment says. You mean I should use the word "unitary ball"?

Comment: @Majid:  Yes, to avoid confusion; by your definition, $\Sigma_2$ is not a sphere, even if $\Sigma_1$ is.

Comment: @RobertBryant Now I understood what you mean. Let me see how to correct the question.

Comment: @RobertBryant Is that ok now?

Comment: @BenMcKay Your answer is definitely an answer to the previous version of my question. Thanks.